# Keyboard shortcut to take a screenshot in Blender 2.83

Tags: shortcut

The available method is under 'Window' in the top menu. However, I would like to use a shortcut to take a screenshot in Blender 2.83. How do I do this?

Comment: generally screenshots are printscreen button. hang on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

right click on the ScreenShot menu item, click assign shortcut. That should get you started
[image: add a shortcut]

Comment: Thanks a lot @4nof

Comment: welcome :)  You can also shortcut just about anything else in blender